# ldap_add error too vague

Tags: php, ldap

I am using php-ldap to manage posix accounts on a linux machine. I am able to search the database in php. And I am able to add users via the command line "ldapadd". However, when I try to add a user via PHP ldap_add, I get an "Object class violation" error (errno 65).

I have tried everything I can think of, but the error has not changed. I have even looked to see if there is an alternative to php-ldap, but have not found one.

The problem is when I look up that error in the general LDAP guide, it says "This error is returned with the entry to be added or the entry as modified violates the object class schema rules. Normally additional information is returned the error detailing the violation." And then it lists 8 possible causes.

I need this more in depth error, but cannot find it. ldap_error was also no help. Any ideas how to dig deaper here?

Comment: One possible [cause/solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=533630)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I am not using samba though. And I was able to create a user with phpldapadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to dig deeper. I am using Ubuntu which was dumping logs to /var/log/{debug,syslog}

In order to get more info I had to increase the log level to 424 in /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif

Then I was able to see the error in the logs which told me what I was doing wrong... using a dc attribute with an inetOrgPerson objectClass.

Thanks.

Comment: Well that is an interesting issues.

Answer (score 1):

Object class violation always means the object you created violated the expectations of the schema.

slapd provides a metric ton of logging if you simply set the debug level to some arbitarily high number.

Answer (score 0):

PosixAccount (the class that is needed for Linux users) has some mandatory attributes.  You must provide in the same operation the:

- uid
- uidNumber
- gidNumber
- homeDirectory

Perhaps in one approach you are, one you are not?

Comment: I have these values in both the PHP and the command line version.

Comment: @Jono: Well because they are mandatory, the modify of objectClass and the add of all the attributes must happen in the same event.  If they come in two events it will fail.

Comment: I am never modifying. Only adding.

Comment: @Jono: Alas, you THINK you are only adding.  :)  Prove it.  :)  Show me the LDAP server logs, and you might be surprised.  Seriously though, under the covers you might be surprised how things are done.

Comment: yes. thanks for the tip to look at the logs. that is what I was looking for. logs with more info about my error.

Answer (score 0):

A [comment](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-error.php#121881) under ldap_error documentation says that to obtain additional info you can call this:

```
ldap_get_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $err);
// $err now contains the additional info
```

Answer (score -1):

We had the same problems, so we used the following bash command:

```
sudo tail -f syslog |grep slapd
```

So you will have an real time window to show you the detail reactions on your LDAP manipulations.